# Firebase Google authentication Web (PHP) wrong Issuer

Tags: php, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I don't get the Firebase Google authentication on my Webpage work maybe someone can give me a hint what i'm missing. Login with E-Mail and Password against Firebase works fine.

I always getting the message:

> THE VALUE 'XXX...' IS NOT A VERIFIED ID TOKEN: - - THE TOKEN WAS NOT
> ISSUED BY THE GIVEN ISSUERS - - THE TOKEN IS NOT ALLOWED TO BE USED BY
> THIS AUDIENCE INVALID TOKEN

In Firebase i enabled Google sign-in and specified the Client ID and Client Secret:
[image: Firebase config]

And also on Google Console the "Client ID" is enabled:
[image: Google cloud]

If i check the Token on "jwt.io" i get also the correct Client ID "aud": "XXXXX9knrrt.apps.googleusercontent.com""

Here is my Code:

```
 <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
                            <div id="g_id_onload"
                                data-client_id="<?php echo GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID; ?>"
                                data-login_uri="https://MY.url/login.php"
                            >
                            </div>

    if (isset($_POST['credential'])) {
    // Receive the Google ID token from the POST request
    $google_id_token = $_POST['credential'];
    //print_r($google_id_token);

    try {
        $verifiedIdToken = $auth->verifyIdToken($google_id_token);
        
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        // Handle token validation errors
        $errors .= 'Google Sign-In Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        
    }
}
```